# Complex Birthday Problem

Tags: probability

I'm overwhelmed by this one: what are the chances of 3 unrelated individuals having not only the same birthday, but the same birth year??  This happened to me about a year ago at a party with 28 people present.  I was skeptical enough to check IDs, and all 3 birthdays were verified August 17,1975.

Comment: Interesting. Were the 28 people your former classmates, colleagues, or friends?

Comment: This is a question with no clear answer in that it depends on the nature of the party. If it is for instance a classmate reunion. the number of years in which those classmates can be born is limited to a few years. If instead this is a family reunion spanning several generations, the number of years is much larger _but_ the distribution of the years cannot be uniform.

Comment: At a basic level, once the number $N$ of years is set, this is a traditional birthday problem with $365\times N$ days.

Comment: See http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/3207/919 for more information about the reasons for closing this question.